# Look up MX server and display

Tags: php, email, dns

I'm trying to make a script that receives "email" in GET and then displays MX server and i tired this code it did not work!

```
<?php
   $email = $_GET['email'];
   list($username,$domain) = split("@",$email);
   echo getmxrr($domain)
?>
```

Comment: What output did you get and what output did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
<?php
//$email = $_GET['email'];
//list($username,$domain) = split("@",$email);
//echo getmxrr($domain)

   $email = $_GET['email'];
   list($username,$domain) = split("@",$email);
   $mxlist = array();
   echo getmxrr($domain,$mxlist);
   foreach($mxlist as $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
    }
?>
```